# WinForms. Как реализовать полиморфизм для рисования фигур?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть задание: "Используя динамические объекты и виртуальные методы,
разработать программу вывода на экран и смены цвета рамки,
состоящей из двух квадратов"

Я создал класс MyRectangles, рисующий прямоугольники одного цвета, и класс RedRectangles рисующий те же квадраты но другого цвета.
Но почему то ничего не рисуется.
Как правильно реализовать полиморфизм для моего примера?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _rectangleXPosition;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyRectangles rectangles = new MyRectangles();
        rectangles.OnPaint();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

class MyRectangles : Form
{

    public virtual void OnPaint()
    {

        Graphics dc = CreateGraphics();
        dc.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 5, 5, 750, 400);
        dc.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 740, 380);

    }
}

 class RedRectangles : MyRectangles
{


    public override void OnPaint()
    {
        Graphics dc = CreateGraphics();
        dc.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 5, 5, 750, 400);
        dc.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 740, 380);

    }
}
```

Comment: А где должно рисоваться то? Объект `Graphics` то куда-то еще нужно вывести же. И, тут вам не нужно наследование - просто свойство цвет у класса `Rectangles`

Comment: Должно отображаться на форме. Мне по заданию нужно именно реализовать вывод через виртуальные методы

Comment: Так должно отображаться - так вы сформируйте битмап, выведите его в какой-то имейдж на форме или вы думаете, что оно само себя все нарисует по мановению волешбной палочики?

Comment: Не рисуется потому, что вы вместо рисования создаете новую форму и для нее вызываете метод рисования. Оно рисуется, но не в вашем окне, а в скрытом, т.к. вы не вызываете метод Show у новой формы. Сомневаюсь что именно этого вы хотели добиться, лучше опишите простыми словами что вы хотите сделать, без терминологии, которую вы, судя по всему, не до конца понимаете. Перегрузка методов - тоже полиморфизм, только другого рода.

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса, задачу которую мне надо сделать. 
По факту хочу сделать класс MyRectangles, рисующий на форме черные квадраты, унаследовать от него другой класс с другим цветом квадратов и выводить квадраты разных цветов в зависимости от объекта который вызывается

Comment: Куда выводить? как выводить? Вообще за формулировку задачи, подозреваю учебной, автора надо бить ногами, если конечно это авторский текст, а не после вашей "адаптации". Тут вариантов решения как сказок у Шехерезады...

Comment: Задача учебная, слово в слово, без адаптации))

Comment: Ночером набросаю вариант, заодно распишу подробно ваши текущие ошибки. Ну или может еще кто отпишется. Сама по себе задача простая, только не нужно ваши классы наследовать от формы, в худшем случае от UserControl, а по хорошему у вас должен быть класс модели вашей рамки, в объетах которого, вы задаете ее параметры, а потом рисуете, переопредлив для этого метод OnPaint основной формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок, для начала ошибки или почему

> Но почему то ничего не рисуется

Оставляю только необходимый код из вашего с моими комментариями:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //создаете новый объект наследника формы, но этого не достаточно
        //для его отображения
        MyRectangles rectangles = new MyRectangles();
        //вызываете метод OnPaint у новой формы, но этого тоже не достаточно,
        //для того, чтобы окно появилось на экране
        rectangles.OnPaint();
    }
    ...
}

class MyRectangles : Form //наследуетесь от формы (для простоты, от окна)
{
   ...
}

class RedRectangles : MyRectangles //продолжаете наследоваться от формы
{
   ...
}
```

Чтобы отобразить созданный объект `MyRectangles`, нужно вызвать у него метод `Show()`, но это не решает вашу проблему, так как это приведет к открытию дополнительного окна, а я сильно сомневаюсь что вам нужно именно это. При этом, даже если вы откроете это новое окно, то в нем тоже ни чего не будет нарисовано, так как сигнатура вашего метода `OnPaint()` не совпадает с сигнатурой оригинального метода, который вызывается автоматически, а значит кто-то должен будет его вызвать принудительно.

Я не знаю, что именно хотел сказать автор задания, и, тем более, что хотел получить от вас на выходе (руки бы оторвал за такую формулировку учебных заданий), поэтому пойдем наиболее простым, но правильным, с точки зрения выбранной платформы, путем.

Дополнительные классы вам не потребуются, все уже придумано до вас, надо только правильно этим воспользоваться, например так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //добавим поле для хранения цвета рамки со значением по-умолчанию
    private Color _boderColor = Color.Black;

    //переопределяем виртуальный метод формы OnPaint
    //именно он вызывается автоматически для отрисовки содержимого формы.
    override protected void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    { 
        //вызываем оригинальный метод предка, чтобы не потерять базовую функциональность
        base.OnPaint(e);
        //готовим рамку с заданными параметрами
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(5, 5, 750, 400));
        gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(10, 10, 740, 380));
        //При использовании разных цветов для контура рамки и заливки
        //сначала закрашиваем рамку
        e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(_boderColor), gp);
        //потом рисуем рамку
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(_boderColor), gp);           
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        //Конструктор не трогаем, без крайней необходимости
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...       
}
```

Аналогично цвету, можете параметризовать толщину рамки, цвет заливки рамки, отступ от края формы и другие параметры, которыми захочется управлять при отрисовке. Теперь осталось добавить на форму кнопку, в обработчике которой, вызовем [ColorDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) для выбора цвета и запишем его в поле `_boderColor`. Главное, после выбора цвета, не забыть вызвать метод формы `Refresh()`, чтобы форма была перерисована и изменение цвета отразилось на рамке.

Также советую подписаться на событие формы [ClientSizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx), и принудительно вызывать в нем `Refresh()`, чтобы не возникало артефактов при изменении размера окна.

И еще один момент, про который вам наверняка забудут рассказать, почитайте про свойство [Control.ClientSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize(v=vs.110).aspx), чтобы не возникало вопросов, почему изображение не умещается на форме или контроле.

Что касается полиморфизма - все в наличии. Ваша форма наследует весь функционал родительского класса Form и изменяет поведение базового метода OnPaint.

Заготовка у вас есть, остальное уже ваша работа, причем самая главная ее часть - разобраться как это работает, а MSDN может в этом серьезно помочь, например рабочими примерами кода и даже пошаговыми инструкциями для типовых задач. Привыкайте читать документацию - это крайне полезное занятие.